# What does it mean to have a directory name prefixed with two dots?

Tags: linux, shell, ls

I got the below file hierarchy in my Linux system. Wondering what it means to have two dots prefixed to a directory name?

```
/run/mydir # ls -la
total 4
drwxrwxrwt    3 root     root           140 Sep 22 13:03 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Sep 30 06:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root           100 Sep 22 13:03 ..2019_09_22
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            31 Sep 22 13:03 ..data -> ..2019_09_22
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            13 Sep 22 13:03 address -> ..data/address
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            16 Sep 22 13:03 name -> ..data/name
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root            12 Sep 22 13:03 cell -> ..data/cell

/run/mydir # ls -la ../
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Sep 30 06:26 .
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Sep 30 06:26 ..
drwxrwxrwt    3 root     root           140 Sep 22 13:03 mydir
/run/mydir #
```

Comment: Note that questions about UNIX usage (rather than *writing code* on or for UNIX systems) belong on [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It has no significance except that `ls` will not normally list the names because the first character is a dot `.`.  To see names beginning with a dot, you need `ls -a` or thereabouts, as you show.  It looks like a convention that someone with root privileges on your machine likes as a way to identify other directories, but that's about all.

We could guess that over time, there might eventually be other directories such as `..2019_09_29` and that `..data` might be rigged to point to the directory currently being analyzed, but that's guesswork.

Answer (score -1):

There are always two default directories:

1. single period (.) = Current Directory
2. Double Period (..) = Parent Directory

Comment: But the question is about `..data` and `..2019_09_22` rather than `.` and `..`.  Plain `.` doesn't have two dots; `..` doesn't really have two dots as a prefix.